# Вернуть объект, отсортировав его по минимальному значению

Tags: javascript, объекты

[image: объект данных]

Никак не могу вспомнить, как из этих объектов вернуть один с минимальным значением distance, подскажите плз как реализовать. `Math.min`? или может методом `find`?

```
 for (let point of this.points){
      const res = {title: point.title, distance : point.getDistance(x,y,z).toFixed(0)};
      console.log(res);
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let data = [{
    title: 'a',
    distance: '193'
  },
  {
    title: 'b',
    distance: '1175'
  },
  {
    title: 'c',
    distance: '365'
  }
]
let res = data.reduce((res, point) => {
  if (parseInt(point.distance) < parseInt(res.distance)) res = point;
  return res;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: присваивать res, в данном случае, не надо, достаточно сразу вернуть point, и в этом случае функция станет однострочной: `(res, point) => (parseInt(point.distance) < parseInt(res.distance)) ? point:res`

Comment: Да, я, в принципе, об этом думал, но решил, что так будет чуть нагляднее. :)

Comment: `reduce` конечно метод, что надо. Надо изучить и взять на заметку, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
let min = {title: 'Not found', distance: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY};
for (let point of this.points){
   const res = {title: point.title, distance: point.getDistance(x,y,z).toFixed(0)};
   if(res.distance < min.distance) min = res;
}
return min;
```

Comment: Вот только `toFixed()`-то возвращает строку, соответственно далее идет сравнение строк со всеми вытекающими неожиданностями. :)